# Folder missing either before or after Chkdsk ran in verify mode

Tags: windows, windows-8, ntfs, data-recovery, chkdsk

When I started my computer I was shown a popup window asking to check the disk of H:, I chose the scan mode that only checks and would allow me to choose what to do. I wasn't asked again if I should repair or fix anything, it ended with a success that the disk had been checked and everything was fine.

I noticed about one hour afterwards that a folder had gone missing from the drive H:. 
The folder was **H:\Lightroom Catalog**

Now, I can't find any *.chk files on the drive (I read somewhere that restore is possible from these) 
I've enabled view of hidden files and system files.

I can find the below event logs in Windows Logs > Application

```
Type: Information
Date and time: 2014-07-01 18:08:54
Source: Chkdsk
Event Id: 26226

Chkdsk was executed in scan mode on a volume snapshot.  

Checking file system on H:
Volume label is FILESRV.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...

  391680 file records processed.                                                         File verification completed.

  110 large file records processed.                                                                                                                           
  0 bad file records processed.                                      
Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...

  455594 index entries processed.                                                        Index verification completed.
                                                                                            Found lost file "\FILESRV <0x1,0x2a70e>"; requesting reconnection to index "$I30" of directory "\ <0x5,0x5>"
        ... repaired online.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.

  31957 data files processed.                                            Windows has found problems and they were all fixed online.
No further action is required.

   2621439 MB total disk space.
 807818740 KB in 336083 files.
    152044 KB in 31959 indexes.
    539612 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
1875844160 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 671088639 total allocation units on disk.
 468961040 allocation units available on disk.

----------------------------------------------------------------------


Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
CHKDSK is scanning unindexed files for reconnect to their original directory.
Recovering orphaned file FILESRV (173838) into directory file 5.
Recovering orphaned file FILESRV (173838) into directory file 5.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
```

And also this:

```
Type: Information
Date and time: 2014-07-01 19:25:37
Source: Chkdsk
Event Id: 26228    

Chkdsk was executed in verify mode on a volume snapshot.  

Checking file system on \Device\HarddiskVolume26
Volume label is FILESRV.

Examining 1 corruption record ...

Record 1 of 1: Corrupt File "\Lightroom Catalog <0x9,0x24544>" ... no corruption found.

1 corruption record processed in 0.1 seconds.

Windows has examined the list of previously identified potential issues and found no problems.
No further action is required.
```

<del>***How should I go ahead and proceed to restore or recover the missing folder H:\Lightroom Catalog?***</del>

**Update:** Files have been restored successfully using ZAR (Zero Assumption Recovery) after 13 hours of scanning. Thanks [Jakke](https://superuser.com/users/281681/jakke) for your similar suggestions.

### However,

***I still* would like to know why the folder was removed even though I told chkdsk to only verify/scan and show me the results. And because of the fact that it was removed, why and where the *.chk-files went?** 

Please try translating that log for me, as I cannot really understand what part of that log that says the folder was removed.

I am running Windows 8.1 x64.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check all your drives to see if the folder has accidentally been moved to another drive (I see this all too often with people using drag-and-drop without realizing it). If you are certain that the files are gone, there are a lot of free file recovery tools that you can try. Have a look at majorgeeks.com for example (http://www.majorgeeks.com/mg/sortname/data_recovery_233b.html). If that folder has been removed and no other data has overwritten the space, it's very likely that everything can be restored.

Comment: No folder accidently moved. As you see in the log above, chkdsk has clearly gone through the \Lightroom Catalog. Now, I wonder where those *.chk files or the FOLDER.001 went, these are usually created by chkdsk.


I ended up starting up ZAR (Zero Assumption Recovery) and allowed the program the whole night to scan through the disk of files that were deleted/recoverable. I had 100% success rate recovering the folder and files within it.

Comment: I'm glad you have your files back. If my comment helped you resolve your problem, please consider marking it as an answer. Thank you :)

Comment: I would do it, even though I managed without but I still have a couple of concerns. Your suggestions are similar like the road I went down eventually, and besides you were the only one giving a suggestion.

But I still would like to know why the folder was removed even though I told chkdsk to only verify/scan and show me the results - and because of the fact that it was removed, why and where the *chk-files went.

Comment: If you find my question useful and clear, please consider voting on it.

Answer (score -1):

i have that same question. i cant find anything online.

the other major step that wasnt explained here is HOW TO FIX THE DRIVE.
yes, you have your files but the drive is a complete mess.

if you go to your folder view options and uncheck all the "hide etc" options so everything is visible.

You can access your moved files on the original drive without needing to recover anything.

heres how I FIXED the drive, i copied all my data to a different hard drive. then i formatted the problem drive.
then i moved all my programs and files back to the formatted drive. all my desktop shortcuts work fine.